# Conversion of automatically generated R code into C

Tags: c, r, automation, code-translation

I have a function that looks like this:

> .e1 <- exp(B); .e2 <- t - C; .e3 <- exp(A); .e4 <- .e1 * .e2; .e5 <- dnorm(.e4); .e6 <- .e5 * .e3; .e7 <- .e6 + tol; .e8 <- sigma^2; .e9 <- .e7^2; .e10 <- Y - .e6; .e11 <- .e8 * .e9; .e12 <- .e11^2; .e13 <- dnorm(.e4, 0, 1); .e14 <- .e1^2; .e15 <- sigma^4; .e16 <- (2 * (.e8 * .e7 * .e10/.e12) + 2/.e11) * .e10; .e18 <- 2/.e7; .e19 <- .e15 * .e7^4; .e20 <- 2/.e8; .e21 <- .e2^2; .e24 <- 2 * .e6 + 4 * (.e19 * .e10/.e12) + tol; .e25 <- 6 * .e7; .e26 <- (2 - .e20)/.e9; .e27 <- .e26 + .e8 * (2 * (Y - .e24) - .e25) * .e10/.e12; .e30 <- .e27 * .e5 * .e3 + .e16; .e31 <- 4 * (.e19/.e12); .e33 <- (2 + 4 * (.e15 * .e7^3 * .e10/.e12)) * .e7; .e38 <- 2 * .e10; .e39 <- .e18 - .e30; .e40 <- sigma * (2 * ((2 - .e31) * .e10) - 4 * .e7); .e43 <- .e8 * (2 * (.e24 - Y) + .e25) * .e10/.e12;

This continues for over 100kb.

The function was the result of using `Deriv` to differentiate a complicated function several times. There is a large number of intermediate assignments in this function because Deriv is set to cache re-used expressions, though ultimately this is a simple function that takes in 6 arguments and produces a simple array. It could be a one-liner... if you tolerate a gigantic line length. The function is composed of simple arithmetic operations, and a few maths functions (exp, log...). There are no loops or flow control.

My question is:

1. Would a function of this particular form be substantially faster to run in C? I understand that generally things run faster in compiled code, however would the bottleneck here be interpreting the language or more unavoidable things like all the assignments?
2. Does it seem plausible to automatically try and translate simple code like this to C? The code seems far too long to do it by hand. If someone has done it before, that would help.

Comment: 1. C should be faster anyway - compiler will try to pipeline Your code and so forth. 2. Translation should be pretty straightforward, just replace `<-` with `=` and add semicolns and type declarations

Comment: The optimized compilation of the generated C could take quite a long time (perhaps dozens of minutes). I guess the translation from R to C could be coded in R (you would work on the internal [SEXP](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPs)s)

Comment: LOL!! .................

Comment: @bartop: not as easy. Replace `^` by ... what? `pow()` ? maybe in C++ with operator redefinition. But doesn't work on basic types.

Comment: but doable, and will probably speed this code by 200 or 300%

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch if it isn't weeks that's still fine, this code is expected to be run many times.